# How to lower the search Icon in my actionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-search, android-icons

For some reason my search icon is positioned a little bit higher than the settings icon. How do I lower the position of the search icon to match the settings icon in actionBar. Here's what I mean:

[image]

Here's my code for search icon, I got this icon from the Android Studio Image Asset Clip Art.

```
<item



    android:id="@+id/menuSearch"
    android:title="@string/search"
    android:hint="@string/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"

     />
```

How do I lower the search icon ?

Answer (score 0):

If the concern is only lowering it down, you can try:

- Adding some top margin
- Negative bottom margin

> PS: we should do this only if the image has an included bottom
>   padding, otherwise it may not appear correctly on other
>   devices if the reason is unknown.  (Maybe include some more top-level hierarchy
>   code as well)